# Как извлечь данные из xml файла, JS

Tags: javascript, xml

Столкнулся  с проблемой, подключаюсь  к xml файлу, в нём есть теги  `offers>offer`.

Получаю массив тегов, где содержится вся информация: заголовок, описание, размер, цена и т.д.  Но проблема в том, что размеры есть у основного  товара и у цвета товара, и эти данные нвходятся в разных офферах. Мне  нужно  их  как-то  отфильтровать.

В коде, представленном ниже, я фильтрую по `vendorCode`, но у цвета и у  основной карточки разные `vendorCode`.

Хочу создать новый массив c объектами, но там не за что зацепиться, чтобы собрать данные как единый товар. Какие еcть мысли по этому поводу?

Сайт с примером: https://kwork.aswebgroups.ru

Мой код:

```js
const url = 'https://kwork.aswebgroups.ru/proxy.php?url=https://fireboxstore.ru/link/789ed662efe90852e79444d36545af7deda4d94a.xml';
const parser = new DOMParser();
const mycart = document.getElementById('mycart');
const mycartbt = document.getElementById('mycartbt');
let count = 3;
let card = '';
const uniqueIds = new Set();
const el = [];
let missingSizeOffers=[];

mycartbt.addEventListener('click', displayProductCards);

async function loadOffers() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const xmlData = await response.text();
        const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlData, 'text/xml');
        const offers = xmlDoc.querySelectorAll('shop > offers > offer');
        console.log( offers[7])
        offers.forEach(function (e) {
            const id = e.getAttribute('id');
            const url = e.querySelector('url').textContent;
            const vendorCode = e.querySelector('vendorCode').textContent;
            let nameParam = e.querySelector('param[name="Размер"]') != null?e.querySelector('param[name="Размер"]').textContent:"";
            //8missingSizeOffers.push(nameParam);
    
            const pictures = [...e.querySelectorAll('picture')];
         
            var picture= pictures.map(function (el) {
                return el.textContent
            });

            if (uniqueIds.has(id) || el.some(item => item.vendorCode === vendorCode)) {
                //  missingSizeOffers=[]
                return; // Пропустить дубликаты
            }
            //console.log(missingSizeOffers)

            const name = e.querySelector('name').textContent;
            const description = e.querySelector('description').textContent;

            el.push({
                name,
                url,
                description,
                picture,
                id,
                vendorCode,
            });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Ошибка загрузки данных:', error);
    }
}

function displayProductCards() {
    card = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (i >= el.length) {
            // Все товары добавлены
            break;
        }

        const id = el[i].id;

        if (uniqueIds.has(id)) {
            continue; // Пропустить дубликат
        }

        uniqueIds.add(id);

        card += `
        <div class="cart">
        <h3 class="product-name">${el[i].name}</h3>
        <div class="img_carts"><img src="${el[i].picture[1]}" alt="${el[i].name}"></div>
        <p class="product-description">${el[i].description}</p>
        <a href="${el[i].url}" target="_blank">Подробнее</a>
        </div>
        `;
    }

    mycart.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', card);
    count += 3;
}

async function loadProductCards() {
    await loadOffers();
    displayProductCards();
}

loadProductCards();
```

```css
html,body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    line-height:1.3;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    height: 100%;
}
*{
    box-sizing:border-box; 
}
/* Стили для карточек товара */
.product-card {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.product-name {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.product-description {
    margin-top: 10px;  
}
.container {
    max-width: 1200px ;
    margin: 100px auto;
    height: 100%;
}
/* Стили для кнопки "Добавить в корзину" */
.row {
    padding: 0 20px;
    display: flex;
    gap:18px;
    flex-flow: wrap row;
}
.cart a {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.cart {
    width: calc(100%/4) ;   
    flex: 1 0 calc(100%/4) ;    
}
.img_carts img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    height: auto;
}
.img_carts {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
#mycartbt {
    display:block;
    background-color: #0074d9;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    width: 124px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="mycart">
        <!-- Здесь будут отображаться карточки товара -->
    </div>
    <button id="mycartbt">показать ещё </button>
</div>
```